# Can't change Icon of a DMG or air package in osx Mavericks

Tags: macos, icons, osx-mavericks, dmg-image

Hello I was hoping someone would be able to help. I'm attempting to make a fancy DMG for program I have developed for the company but keep coming up short when I try to change the icon when I view the contents of the folder/file.

I'm starting to wander whether something in Mavericks is simply stopping me from changing an icon on my custom dmg. To break it down.

- Opened up the contents of the file
- Drag - copy and paste the file over the icon in the top left (plus icon appears)
- The file(s) fail to change correctly, 'paste' is greyed out when to copy and paste the icon into the position. A generic icon is replaced instead of what I copied over. Its a jpg image with "ICO" written in the bottom of graphic
- I have the read write permissions (I published the file)

Is there a way of making this work? Please note I'm unfamiliar with working with terminal. I'm also open to programs which may give me the results I need that will overwrite the setting of that icon on that file.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to change the ICON of the DMG or the background-image for the window that opens when you open the DMG?

Comment: Hello, the ICON. I've managed to change the BG image for the window. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Result! This did the trick.

- Go to "Get info" of the file's icon you want to change.
- Open the image (PNG) of the image you are wanting to use in **Preview** (or a graphics editor)
- "**select**" the image, and 'Copy' (Command-C) it
- Go back to the "Get info" window and 'Paste' (Apple V) the image (the png you have selected) into the Preview Panel

This worked for me.

*Don't drag the file to the top left of "Get Info", it doesn't appear to work properly. OSX V 10.8.5 - Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

When I want to change the ICON of a DMG-File I select the DMG-File in Finder, Hit CMD-I (or use the *Information* entry from the context-menu). Then select the Icon in the top-left corner of the Information-window and paste the relevant graphic into it.

When I want to change the Background-Image of a Finder-Window, I open up the window, I want to change, hit CMD-J and select "Image" as Background-Option. Then I paste the image into the now available Upload-Box. Set the other view-options you want to be available and close the DMG. That's it.

Comment: Hello Heiglandreas, I've managed to get that far and I mentioned in my query that I have got that far with dropping an image across/into the icon in the top left corner. I'm more stuck with why my computer is acting strangely when I try to do this... ie the image wont swap. Thanks for the answer anyway. I may have to get more into the nuts and bolts of this.

Comment: I'm assuming that you do have the access rights to change the file and that you have the file on a HFS+ formated drive. Can you change the icon of any othe file that lies right beneath the DMG?

Comment: Yeah I assume so. In the bottom next to my name I have "Read & Write". Sorry what is a HFS+ formatted drive? No, I can't change the icon of any file. When I drag it over it swaps the image over for a generic icon with "ICO" written in the bottom. Any clues?

Comment: Is the DMG located on a server volume or on your local hard drive? If it's on a server volume do you connect via smb or afp?

Comment: No that's fine. :-) Yes, i'm working on a Mac, i'm working on my Local Drive.

Comment: thats really strange as it should work that way. can you post a screenshot of the "Get Info" window?

Comment: I need a rep of 10 plus to add images apparently. Much the same though I can't drag the image over the folder. It may be worth mentioning that I downloaded this. http://www.panic.com/blog/candybar-mountain-lion-and-beyond/

I wouldn't really say this solves my issue though. As I would like to be able to change the dmg icon without all this fussing over with 3rd party software. Thx